# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function discord.js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a command to fetch data from a API to display on a image but I keep getting this error:

```
    /media/bobby/Hardrive/NEW PC/Public/commands/now.js:16
            const background = await Canvas.loadImage('https://lgbtqlounge.xyz/assets/img/canvas.png')
                               ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/bobby/Hardrive/NEW PC/Public/index.js:14:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

This is my code:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const Canvas = require("canvas")

module.exports = {
    name: 'now',
    description: 'Tells you what is live on LGBTQLounge Radio!',
    async execute(message, args) {
        fetch("http://api.lgbtqlounge.xyz/radio").then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
            const title = res.song.song
            const artist = res.song.artist
            const art = res.song.art
            const currentDJ = res.currentdj.name

            const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(1250, 500)
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
            const background = await Canvas.loadImage('https://lgbtqlounge.xyz/assets/img/canvas.png')
            ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b'
            ctx.strokeRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            ctx.font = 'bold 48px "Noto Sans", sans-serif'
            ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'
            ctx.fillText(`${title} by ${artist}`, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 2.6)
            ctx.font = 'bold 72px "Noto Sans", sans-serif'
            ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'
            ctx.fillText(currentDJ, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.6)
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.arc(235, 244, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
            ctx.closePath()
            ctx.clip()
            ctx.drawImage(art, 85, 95, 300, 300)
            const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'now.png')
          
            message.channel.send(attachment);
        })
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me with this issue it will be gladly appreciated!

Thanks for any help in advance and I hope everyone is having a great day (it aint letting me post because most of it is code so gotta elaborate a bit more so I am hving the most fun of my life)

Comment: You are missing the function like this ```async function execute(message, args)```.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `await` is only valid in `async` function, you need to wrap your code in a `async` function. Your `execute` function is `async` but the direct parent function of `const background = await Canvas.loadImage` is not async which is callback of `.then`.

```
fetch("http://api.lgbtqlounge.xyz/radio").then(res => res.json())
     .then(async res => {
            const title = res.song.song
            const artist = res.song.artist
            const art = res.song.art
            const currentDJ = res.currentdj.name

            const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(1250, 500)
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
            const background = await Canvas.loadImage('https://lgbtqlounge.xyz/assets/img/canvas.png')
            ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b'
            ctx.strokeRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            ctx.font = 'bold 48px "Noto Sans", sans-serif'
            ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'
            ctx.fillText(`${title} by ${artist}`, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 2.6)
            ctx.font = 'bold 72px "Noto Sans", sans-serif'
            ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'
            ctx.fillText(currentDJ, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.6)
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.arc(235, 244, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
            ctx.closePath()
            ctx.clip()
            ctx.drawImage(art, 85, 95, 300, 300)
            const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'now.png')
          
            message.channel.send(attachment);
        })
```

Making callback function as `async` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error here is pretty clear: you can only use `await` within an `async` function.

Your use of `await` here is actually in a nested function:

```js
async execute(message, args) {
    fetch("http://api.lgbtqlounge.xyz/radio").then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
        ...
        const background = await Canvas.loadImage('https://lgbtqlounge.xyz/assets/img/canvas.png')
        ...
    })
}
```

The `await` is located in `res => { ... }`, not within `async execute() { ... }`.

The simplest (as in "least work") fix here is to make the nested function an `async` function:

```js
fetch("http://api.lgbtqlounge.xyz/radio")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(async res => { ... })
```

However, you are actually mixing usage of `async`/`await` with conventional `.then()` promise chaining. The *proper* fix would be to switch the whole function to use one or the other, preferably `async`/`await` because it is easier to read:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'now',
    description: 'Tells you what is live on LGBTQLounge Radio!',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const res = await fetch("http://api.lgbtqlounge.xyz/radio")
        const json = await res.json()
        const title = json.song.song
        const artist = json.song.artist
        const art = json.song.art
        const currentDJ = json.currentdj.name

        const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(1250, 500)
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        const background = await Canvas.loadImage('https://lgbtqlounge.xyz/assets/img/canvas.png')
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b'
        ctx.strokeRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        ctx.font = 'bold 48px "Noto Sans", sans-serif'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'
        ctx.fillText(`${title} by ${artist}`, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 2.6)
        ctx.font = 'bold 72px "Noto Sans", sans-serif'
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'
        ctx.fillText(currentDJ, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.6)
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(235, 244, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.clip()
        ctx.drawImage(art, 85, 95, 300, 300)
        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'now.png')
          
        message.channel.send(attachment);
    }
}
```